# what is the Linux equivalent to event log on windows

Tags: linux, events

I wanted to do some diagnostics on a software that is running on one of my Linux machines, it keeps crashing and I am having a hard time to figure out what is causing it from within the software itself but I believe there is something to do with the operating system.

is there a command line utility that I can use to see what events happened on ubuntu or a similar distro.

thanks

Comment: `journalctl` if you are using systemd based Linux distribution.

Answer (score 4):

You have the syslog, or messages.log

`/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/messages`: general messages, as well as system-related information. Essentially, this log stores all activity data across the global system.

My recommendation is to use the tail command, to see what happens in real time:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Then you run the application, and you can see what is happening at the same time in the log, when it crashes, you can use `ctrl+c` to escape from syslog, and to see the logs.